# Copy file with swift

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

I am copying a file database with this code

```
try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: storeURL.path, toPath: storeCopyURL.path)
```

I can see that a new sqlite database is created

later, when I try to use this function

```
try! sharedInstance.managedObjectStore.addSQLitePersistentStore(atPath: storeURL.path, fromSeedDatabaseAtPath: storeCopyURL.path, withConfiguration: nil, options: nil)
```

I get an error

> E restkit.core_data:RKManagedObjectStore.m:299 Failed to copy seed
>   database from path ...

Answer (score 30):

To securely copy a file you should use the following extension:

```
extension FileManager {

    open func secureCopyItem(at srcURL: URL, to dstURL: URL) -> Bool {
        do {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dstURL.path) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: dstURL)
            }
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: srcURL, to: dstURL)
        } catch (let error) {
            print("Cannot copy item at \(srcURL) to \(dstURL): \(error)")
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

For anything else regarding CoreData we need more information about your code and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Maulikshah , you can use this extension as FileManager.default.secureCopyItem(at: <source>, to: <destination>)

Comment: Why make instance method of `FileManager` just to call functions of the static `default` FileManager ? I would suggest you delete the `FileManager.default.` parts of the method invocations and call the methods of the `self` instance instead.

Comment: I am getting this error: "Documents” couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it."

Comment: @ShourobDatta you need to allow your executable to access the `Documents` directory in the privacy settings of your account